# Ubuntu lightDM password expiration warning delay

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I enabled some password expiration policies on my Linux box and am able to see a warning when login: `Warning: your password will expire in X days`. This works also on screensaver when entering my password to unlock the session. However, the message disappears rather quickly. I would like to delay it a bit - few seconds will be enough.

How I can do this? If not - how I can delay the session login after the user press "Login" button?

The goal is to make the message stay on the screen a bit longer, so the user can read it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For lightdm, you could try different greeters (lightdm-unity-greeter, lightdm-gtk-greeter); they would have settings in /etc/lightdm/, including at least font size setting and a theme name (you could work on that theme to make the message easier to read). I have not seen those have a delay setting.

It is possible to file bugs against lightdm [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm), if you don't think the above options resolve your query (even if the alternative display managers do the task, the lightdm folks would appreciate feedback).

xdm man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdm) has an "Authentication Widget" section - you can at least set a larger font face for the message, so the few seconds the user gets are enough to read the message.

The same xdm man page suggests that a session is started after a user logs in. For example, I have an *~/.xsession* file which starts an Xfce session; adding a 'sleep 5;' at its top below the #!... line might add a five seconds delay while the 'password expired' message would show up - or it could already disappear before the session starts. I haven't checked.